# Remove duplicate GET parameters from URL

Tags: javascript, query-string

I want remove the duplicate word with regex

```
let url = "/courses?category=programming&filter=free&filter=free"
const az = url.replace(/(\b\S.+\b)(?=.*\1)/g, "").trim();
console.log(az) // /courses?category=programmingfree&filter=free
```

I want to get `/courses?category=programming&filter=free`

Comment: It looks like you do not want to find "words", but the whole query params.

Comment: I dont understand regex if anyone now, please write the correct form of regex

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams) constructor to parse the URL parameters, then [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to convert it to an object (and remove duplicate keys), then parse back into a `URLSearchParams` object, from which you can call `toString()` to get the result:

```js
let url = "/courses?category=programming&filter=free&filter=free"
let [path, params] = url.split("?");
let result = path + '?' + new URLSearchParams(Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams(params))).toString()
console.log(result)
```

Comment: It will not work when we have to pass values in array format

Comment: @Meet what do you mean "array format?" The standard way to pass multiple GET values is to assign the value more than once.

Comment: I am taking multiple inputs as `<input name="filters[]" value="1" />` because of our work flow, and when I submit form, it will pass multiple `filters[]` keys in URL, We can't control that as per my knowledge, It will be great, if you have answer for it